# rules in the realtime database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I don't understand, I want to read and write based on the logged in user database, but this is not working

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Layanan Nasabah" : {
        ".read": "root.child('User/' + auth.uid).exists()",
        ".write": "root.child('User/' + auth.uid).exists()"
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the code

```
 private void tampilData() {
    database.child("Layanan Nasabah").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            snapshot.child("email").equals("User");
            listlayanan = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DataSnapshot item : snapshot.getChildren()){
                pengaduan pgd = item.getValue(pengaduan.class);
                pgd.setKey(item.getKey());
                listlayanan.add(pgd);
            }
            adapterLayanan = new AdapterLayanan(listlayanan, OnprogressActivity.this);
            tv_tampil.setAdapter(adapterLayanan);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). For the database contents, can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Note that "is not working" is really hard to help with, and you'll have a much better chance of getting help if you follow the guidance in [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). --- A first step would be to stop ignoring errors and implementing `onCancelled`. At its minimum that should be `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`.

Comment: The next step would be to debug the app locally, and tell us the outcome of that. If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do? --- With that information, your question will be more answerable, and it'll also become eligible to be reopened.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
{
    “rules”: {
        “.read”: “auth != null”,
        “.write”: “auth != null”
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work